# Why is my Aptana Terminal not configured with standard Terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, aptana, aptana3

I want to use the Terminal built into Aptana Studio 3. I have everything configured on iTerm2/Terminal. I'm developing a Rails project. I do the following to get the server going.

On the Aptana Terminal:

```
$ rails s
Could not find pg-0.17.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

On the regular Terminal or iTerm2:

```
~ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-08-12 16:15:17] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-08-12 16:15:17] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-darwin13.2.0]
[2014-08-12 16:15:17] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2612 port=3000
```

Both Terminals are on the same working directory. I could do `bundle install` on Aptana Terminal, but it is a chain of errors that occurs. I had that similar situation with iTerm2 and Terminal, but it was a very long and tedious process.

How can I properly configure the Aptana Terminal ?